# Count the number of columns that has a true value then divide it to the total number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets assume that the table below is called Table

```
    **---------------------------------------------
    ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4  ...  Total
    --------------------------------------------
    1      1       0      NULL     1          30.33
    2      0       1       1       1          60.12
    3      1       1       0       0          20.12
    4      1       0       1       1          60.12
    5      0      NULL    NULL     1          10.19
    6      1       1      NULL     1          90.00   
    7      0       0      NULL     0          0.00
    --------------------------------------------**
```

I wanted to count and get the average number of columns that has a "true" in it. And display the total average of it in the Total Columns. For example there are 10 columns and 5 columns are true so I divide it and got 50% in total.  Assuming that all of the columns that I will counting are bit and has a value of null,0 and 1. How do I achieve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    100.0*(COALESCE(Col1, 0) + COALESCE(Col2, 0) + ... + COALESCE(Col10, 0)) / 10 AS pct
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you for your response I am new to sql and your feedback was helpful. I was able  to get the desired result. But one thing I noticed. Why is it that when I got a result of 54.550000 and I added Round((100.0*(...)/10),2) the total result does not round of to 55%?

Comment: @Jean2020 You could use `ROUND` on the result to round to the nearest whole number.